# SELECT...INTO в PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно составить и выполнить программу PL/SQL, которая, используя SELECT ... INTO ..., считывает из базы данных номера заказов после 04 января, и выводит результат. Добавить в программу раздел Exception с обработчиком OTHERS, в котором определяется вид ошибки и выводится сообщения об этой ошибке.

Решил я ее через курсор следующим образом:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN(SELECT onum FROM ord WHERE odate > to_date('04.01.2009','dd.mm.yyyy')) LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Заказ №'||i.onum);
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error');
END;
```

Результат выборки:

```
Заказ №3001
Заказ №3003
Заказ №3002
Заказ №3005
Заказ №3006
Заказ №3009
Заказ №3007
Заказ №3008
Заказ №3010
Заказ №3011

Statement processed.


0,00 seconds
```

Но преподаватель не зачел, из-за того, что это сделано не через SELECT...INTO.
Вопрос, как через SELECT...INTO перебрать все значения из столбца, учитывая, что при выборке нескольких строк возникает исключение

Comment: Хм. перебрать строки с select into проблематично, может имелось ввиду select bulk collect into (это все таки разные вещи) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Comment: возможно Ваш вариант имеет больше смысла, но в самом задании преподаватель так написал и в рецензии, "--здесь не нужно использовать курсорный цикл FOR, по заданию нужно использовать команду SELECT … INTO ..". В общем я в смятении. Сейчас попробую разобраться с bulk конструкцией

Comment: ну в bulk будет цикл, правда это не курсор. это обход в цикле коллекции. А при обходе курсором будет FETCH INTO который опять же ну никак не SELECT INTO

Comment: Ага, сейчас то же это смутило немного. Может просто преподаватель хочет, чтобы банально исключение фиксировалось при попытке прогнать через into несколько значений...а сам результат не интересен.

Comment: В общем если узнать это заранее нельзя я бы сделал несколько вариантов, пусть выбирает тот который больше нравится. заодно с коллекциями немного поработаете. лучше знать максимальное количество способов и использовать в работе тот, который в этом  будет наиболее уместным и удобным в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: И если все так, как вы подумали и требуется обычный into я бы предложил отдельно обработать `when no_data_found` и отдельно `others` это частый прием и может ради этого все это задание и затевалось

Comment: Всё просто. В задании не стоит, что надо вывести результат, а только - составить программу, которая выводит результат. Т.е. надо - select .. into ..., блок с when others, который выдаст исключение toо_many_rows и всё.

Comment: так и сделал, отправил повторно на проверку преподавателю. Буду ждать, что скажет)

Comment: "Рецензия:Уважаемый Петровский Алексей Михайлович,

все верно: задание 4 - это задание на обработку исключительной ситуации." 
Всем спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 2):

Если по ТЗ надо обязательно через `SELECT...INTO` делать, то можно так:

Подготовим схему:

```
create table orders1 as 
    select 3000+rownum orderNo, to_date (t.object_value.getClobVal(), 'yyyymmdd') orderDate 
    from xmltable ('20180101 to 20180131') t;

create or replace type orderType force as object (orderNo number, orderDate date, member procedure print);
/
create or replace type ordersType is table of orderType;
/
create or replace type body orderType as
    member procedure print is
    begin 
        dbms_output.put_line ('order: '||orderNo||' / '||to_char (orderDate, 'dd.mm.yy'));
    end;
end;
/
```

Сам блок:

```
declare 
    orders ordersType;
begin 
    select cast (multiset (
        select orderNo, orderDate 
        from orders1
        where orderDate > date'2018-01-04'
        ) as ordersType) into orders
    from dual
    ;
    for i in 1..orders.count loop orders(i).print; end loop;    
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line ('error: '||sqlerrm);  
end;
/
```

Выведет:

> order: 3005 / 05.01.18
>   order: 3006 / 06.01.18
>   order: 3007 / 07.01.18
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Для нескольких записей используется BULK COLLECT

```
v_tab sys.odcivarchar2list;

begin

SELECT onum BULK COLLECT INTO v_tab
FROM ord WHERE odate > to_date('04.01.2009','dd.mm.yyyy')) 

for i in 1..v_tab.count
loop
v_tab(i).print;
end loop;
exception when OTHERS
Dbms_output.put_line('Error');
End;
```

Comment: Давая ответ с телефона 1) вы невнимательно прочитали задание, нужно действительно INTO 2) имеются синтаксические ошибки, код не выполнится 3) форматируется код с телефона очень даже просто.